# PHP - Append elements to array

Tags: php, arrays, append

I have an array that is used to render a graph using PHPGraphLib. I can make this work fine, but only with hard coded values.

I get "`POSSIBLE syntax error`" warning from Netbeans.

What is the correct way of appending elements to this type of array?

```
//Create new graph object and add graph data
$graph = new PHPGraphLib(650,400);
$data = array           ("00:00" => -9,
                        "00:15" => -8,
                        "00:30" => -3.5,
                        "00:45" => 5, 
                        "01:00" => 11,
                        "01:15" => 12.5,
                        "01:30" => 10.5,
                        "01:45" => 11,
                        "02:00" => 2,
                        "02:15" => -2,
                        "02:30" => 2,
                        "02:45" => -2,
                        "03:00" => 14);

array_push($data, "03:15" => 16);  //This is the part I cannot get to work

//Plot data
$graph->addData($data);
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax to add a new element to an associative array is:

```
$data["03:15"] = 16;
```

`array_push` is used with values, not associative elements. It's normally used only with arrays that have numeric indexes, not associative arrays, as it generates the key by adding 1 to the highest numeric index in the array.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your `array_push(...)` with this:

```
$data['03:15'] = 16;
```

With `array_push()` you can only add values to arrays. Not keys as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just append it using shorthand syntax:

```
$data["03:15"] = 16;
```